# Unable to assign variable on namespace scope

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've bumped into [basic.scope.namespace#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.namespace#1) and had something unclear in my mind:

```
namespace Foo {
  int a;
}

namespace Foo {
  // Foo::a = 2;   // Why can't do an assignment here?
  void b() {
      Foo::a = 2;  // OK
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
error: ‘a’ does not name a type
```

I'm curious why we can't have an assignment on namespace scope,

while assignment inside a function block is OK?

Any ideas?

Comment: How can an assignment expression legally appear in namespace scope?

Comment: Your code example somehow does not much code at the link at all. Where did you get *"error: duplicate definition"* from?

Comment: @codekaizer And which compiler issues such a error? [No repro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6cD6RGzDukuCYdo5).

Comment: @VTT, i'm using online compiler - [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/ide)

Comment: @codekaizer It is gcc 6.3 and it does not issue the stated error, instead it reports *"error: ‘a’ in namespace ‘Foo’ does not name a type"*

Comment: @VTT, SORRY! my mistake. i saw my own comment. i've updated the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not have general statements outside of functions.

Perhaps you want a *declaration* in the first place and a *definition* in the second?

Like

```
namespace Foo {
  extern int a;  // Declare variable
}

namespace Foo {
  int a = 2;  // Define and initialize the variable
}
```

Comment: Thank you. makes sense. I'm having a hard time finding that rule in [stmt.stmt](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.stmt). Do you happen to know where can I find more about rules of "general statements"?

Comment: @codekaizer There's no such term as a "general statement". I just meant just about everything that isn't a declaration or a definition (more or less).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm curious why an assignment in namespace scope is treated as definition,

Assignment is an expression statement, and expressions cannot be in the namespace scope. Only declaration statements can be in the namespace scope (definitions are declarations).

> while assignment inside a function block is not?

Expression statements can be in a block scope.